# Passing body in restassured using Generics doesn't work for File and FileInputStream

Tags: rest-assured

In Restassured we can pass the request payload in the body method by different ways like

1. String
2. POJO Object
3. Map Object
4. JsonObject (from GSON library)
5. File and
6. FileInputStream

So, I created following one method using generics to accommodate all these types: -

```
public <T> Response postAMember(T body) {

    return given().spec(this.spec).body(body).when().post(EndPoints.GET_ALL_POST_A_MEMBER).andReturn();
}
```

Now, this is how I'm consuming it for respective Type (Not all in one go...one at a time): -

```
@Test
public void postMember() throws IOException {
    // Using Hashmap
    Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("name", "Rocky");
    body.put("gender", "Male");
    
    // Using Model and GSON
    Member imember = new Member("Rocky", "Male");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
    String body = gson.toJson(imember);
    
    // Using JsonObject (GSON)
    JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
    body.addProperty("name", "Rocky");
    body.addProperty("gender", "Male");
    
    // Using Payload JSON File
    File body = new File("src/test/resources/Payloads/postmemberpayload.json");
    
    // Using Raw String
    String body = "{\r\n" + 
            "   \"name\": \"Rocky\",\r\n" + 
            "   \"gender\": \"Male\"\r\n" + 
            "}";
    
    // Using FileInputStream
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(body); // in this case I would pass fis to body method
    
    Response resp = MemberService.getMemberServiceInstance().postAMember(body);
    Assert.assertEquals(resp.getStatusCode(), StatusCode.CREATED_201);
    Member omember = resp.getBody().as(Member.class);

    System.out.println(omember.toString());

}
```

postAMember method works fine only with : -

1. String
2. POJO Object
3. Map Object
4. JsonObject (from GSON library)

But fails with remaining two: -

5. File - Output is bad request 400
6. FileInputStream - Output is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdk.internal.ref.PhantomCleanable<?> declares multiple JSON fields named next

And for now I've to make following two more overloaded version of postAMember: -

```
public Response postAMember(File body) {

    return given().spec(this.spec).body(body).when().post(EndPoints.GET_ALL_POST_A_MEMBER).andReturn();
}

public Response postAMember(FileInputStream body) {

    return given().spec(this.spec).body(body).when().post(EndPoints.GET_ALL_POST_A_MEMBER).andReturn();
}
```

Now above two methods generate the response. Any clue what's wrong here? Why the method with generics is not able to take File and FileInputStream?

I've fetched the latest Restassured libraries from maven central repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, your generics method will map to `body(Object object)` of `RequestSpecification`, then this `object` will be serialized.

```java
class RequestSpecificationImpl
...

  RequestSpecification body(Object object) {
    ...

    this.requestBody = ObjectMapping.serialize(object, requestContentType, 
               findEncoderCharsetOrReturnDefault(requestContentType), null, 
               objectMappingConfig(), restAssuredConfig().getEncoderConfig());
    ...
  }
```

All below kinds of object has no problem with serialization.

- String
- POJO Object
- Map Object
- JsonObject (from GSON library)

**But**

- File ---serialize---> full path of FILE
- FileInputStream ---serialize---> exception (from Gson/Jackson)

When you add 2 methods, then Rest-Assured correctly map to `body(File body)` and `body(InputStream body)` --> no serialization for them --> no issue.